# How to read user keyboard input?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, winapi

At the moment i use a system such as:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
keys[wParam] = true;
```

Which doesnt work for lowercased letters or special characters such as "&", so im asking is there a winapi function to read keyboard so i could get any 8bit character from user, if he writes "Æ" i would get the corresponding index for that char in this table:

[image]

(in case image not working: http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/1965/asciipage.png )

Im using this table to render text in my OpenGL application, so i need to find from this table which character the user keyboard generated to my program chat line, so im trying to make a chat in my game.

Comment: Your table looks like the Windows ANSI Western character set, except for the character codes <32. Is it meant to be Windows ANSI Western?

Comment: i think it should be `iso-8859-1`, im not entirely sure though. does it matter with the answer below that uses WM_CHAR though?

Comment: i don't think it matters for the control chars (note though that these include newline, backspace, tab and escape), but it does matter for e.g. the Euro currency sign, €. and e.g. the y with two dots on top, ÿ.  In addition Latin-1 lacks 2 whole rows of Windows ANSI Western, but those characters are generally not directly available on a keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the WM_CHAR message which gives you the fully translated character code. Your message loop must use `TranslateMessage` prior to `DispatchMessage` for propper keycode to character translation.

Comment: seems to work perfectly. i noticed the control characters are "visible" in there too, so i suppose the solution is to ignore everything below 32.

Comment: is there some list of the control characters matching to VK_DELETE etc. enums? (VK_DELETE is not the same char as WM_CHAR gives from pressing delete). or what method should i use to process the control chars? edit: actually i cant get VK_DELETE message from this at all... but the others such as VK_BACK doesnt match to the WM_CHAR values. so how could i process delete button in WM_CHAR message handler, or is it even possible?